# Revit Dynamo gives error Data Interpolate python script

Tags: python, interpolation, revit-api

[Interpolate Date- Catmull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPPqj.png)
I am getting the following Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

[Interpolate Date-Linear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDhsO.png)
I am getting the following error: Unexpexted Token "v3"

I am new to Python and wonder what I am doing wrong with this code.
Thanks
Below is the input to D and t.

```
IN[0]
-1.075000
-0.885818
-0.688475
-0.483791
-0.301645
-0.114591
0.077063
0.273042
0.473106
0.677038
1.025973
1.306626
1.592869
1.884406
2.363634
2.597338
2.833636
3.072438
3.313663
3.557232
3.803073
4.051116
4.301297
4.807834
5.069212
5.349055
5.649760
5.971703

IN[1]
0.000000
0.055556
0.111111
0.166667
0.222222
0.277778
0.333333
0.388889
0.444444
0.500000
0.555556
0.611111
0.666667
0.722222
0.777778
0.833333
0.888889
0.944444
1
0.000000
0.027778
0.055556
0.083333
0.111111
0.138889
0.166667
0.194444
0.222222
0.250000
0.277778
0.305556
0.333333
0.361111
0.388889
0.416667
0.444444
0.472222
0.500000
0.527778
0.555556
0.583333
0.611111
0.638889
0.666667
0.694444
0.722222
0.750000
0.777778
0.805556
0.833333
0.861111
0.888889
0.916667
0.944444
0.972222
1

D=IN[0]  
t=IN[1]  
a=[]

def SampleLinear(v0, v1, t):  
    value = v0 * (1.0 - t) + v1 * t  
    return value

def Interpolate (values, parameter):  
    num = len(values) - 1  
    num2 = parameter * float(num)  
    num3 = int((float(floor(num2)))  
    v3 = values[num3]  
    v4 = values[num3]  
    value = SampleLinear(v3, v4, num2 - float(num3))  
    return value  

for i in t:  
    a.append(Interpolate(D,i))

OUT = a
```

---

```
D=IN[0]  
t=IN[1]  
a=[]  



        def SampleCatmull(v00,v0,v1,v11,t):  
           num = -0.5 * v00 + 1.5 * v0 - 1.5 * v1 + 0.5 * v11 
            num2 = v00 - 2.5 * v0 + 2.0 * v1 - 0.5 * v11  
            num3 = -0.5 * v00 + 0.5 * v1  
            value = num * (t * t * t) + num2 * (t * t) + num3 * t + v0  
            return value  



    def Interpolate(values, parameter):  
        num = len(values) - 1  
        num2 = parameter * float(num)  
        num3 = float(floor(num2))  
        num6 = values[num3]  
        v7 = 0  
        v8 = 0  
        num7 = values[num3]  
        if num3 <= 0:  
            v7 = num6 - (num7 - num6)  
        else:  

            v7 = values[num3 - 1]  

        if num3 >= num - 1:  
            v8 = num7 - (num6 - num7)  
        else:  

            v8 = values[num3 + 2]  

        value = SampleCatmull(v7, num6, num7, v8, num2 - float(num3))  

        return value  


    for i in t:  
        a.append(Interpolate(D, i))  

    OUT = a
```

Comment: what's in `IN` ? Please post code and not images.

Comment: IN[0]= Values to interpolate; IN[1]= parameters

Comment: ok but please show a print of your variable `IN`

Comment: 0
0.055556
0.111111
0.166667
0.222222
0.277778
0.333333
0.388889
0.444444
0.5
0.555556
0.611111
0.666667
0.722222
0.777778
0.833333
0.888889
0.944444
1
0
0.027778
0.055556
0.083333
0.111111
0.138889
0.166667
0.194444
0.222222
0.25
0.277778
0.305556
0.333333
0.361111
0.388889
0.416667
0.444444
0.472222
0.5
0.527778
0.555556
0.583333
0.611111
0.638889
0.666667
0.694444
0.722222
0.75
0.777778
0.805556
0.833333
0.861111
0.888889
0.916667
0.944444
0.972222
1

Comment: -1.075
-0.885818
-0.688475
-0.483791
-0.301645
-0.114591
0.077063
0.273042
0.473106
0.677038
1.025973
1.306626
1.592869
1.884406
2.363634
2.597338
2.833636
3.072438
3.313663
3.557232
3.803073
4.051116
4.301297
4.553555
4.807834
5.069212
5.349055
5.64976
5.971703

Comment: at the beginning of your script, can you do `print(IN)` and paste the output in your question, so that people can execute same code as you and see what's the problem

Comment: I have added the input values to the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0):

- In your Interpolate Date-Linear :

You forgot a parenthesis on line `num3 = int((float(floor(num2)))`
Should be : `num3 = int((float(floor(num2))))`

- In your Interpolate Date- Catmull :

when you do :

```
num3 = float(floor(num2)) # num3 is of type float, should be int 
num6 = values[num3]
```

You are trying to access an element of the `values` list by index (`num3`) so your index must be an integer and in your case, it's a Change it to : `num3 = int(floor(num2))`

Comment: Thanks. I changed both lines, but I am I am still getting errors. In the "linear interpolation" the indentation doesn't seem to be correct. and in the "catmull interpolation" the definition expects a single number, but gets a list (even though I am looping through all the inputs from IN[1])

Comment: with the 2 modifications i told you, your code works well.

Answer (score 0):

So the above answer by @arthur is correct that you are trying to pass a `float` into list index query which requires an integer. Changing that line solves the issue for me. Here's an actual image/code snippet from Dynamo.

Another issue that you had was mixing floats `0.00001` with integers in the list `1`. Be consistent.

Ps. On the subject of indentation, I would say that Dynamo, the way it was setup, requires that you pick one style. It's either spaces or either tabs, and it's best to be consistent. I have had some trouble when I was mixing them before (by accident). I reformatted your code and it works fine with all tabs.

[image]

Code:

```
import clr
import sys
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)
from math import floor

def SampleCatmull(v00,v0,v1,v11,t):
    num = -0.5 * v00 + 1.5 * v0 - 1.5 * v1 + 0.5 * v11
    num2 = v00 - 2.5 * v0 + 2.0 * v1 - 0.5 * v11
    num3 = -0.5 * v00 + 0.5 * v1
    value = num * (t * t * t) + num2 * (t * t) + num3 * t + v0
    return value

def Interpolate(values, parameter):
    num = len(values) - 1
    num2 = parameter * float(num)
    num3 = (int)(floor(num2))
    num6 = values[num3] #num3 has to be an index (int)
    v7 = 0
    v8 = 0
    num7 = values[num3]
    if num3 <= 0:
        v7 = num6 - (num7 - num6)
    else:
        v7 = values[num3 - 1]
    if num3 >= num - 1:
        v8 = num7 - (num6 - num7)
    else:
        v8 = values[num3 + 2]
    value = SampleCatmull(v7, num6, num7, v8, num2 - float(num3))
    return value

D=IN[0]
t=IN[1]
a=[]

for i in t:
    a.append(Interpolate(D, i))  
#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = a
```

This is another:

```
import clr
import sys
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)
from math import floor

def SampleLinear(v0, v1, t):
    value = v0 * (1.0 - t) + v1 * t
    return value

def Interpolate (values, parameter):
    num = len(values) - 1
    num2 = parameter * float(num)
    num3 = (int)(floor(num2))
    v3 = values[num3]
    v4 = values[num3]
    value = SampleLinear(v3, v4, num2 - float(num3))
    return value  

D=IN[0]
t=IN[1]
a=[]

for i in t:
    a.append(Interpolate(D,i))
#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = a
```